# Convert to small letters and remove space js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am new to javascript currently working on discord bots
I coded a bot which responds to messages but when I give input in capital letters or by giving space the bot not responding please help me to fix this

This is my code and if I give input like "Hi bro"
It doesn't respond

```
bot.on("message", async message => {
    if(message.author.bot || message.channel.type == 'dm') return;
  
    let prefix = "-";
    let messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
    let cmd = messageArray[0];
    let args = messageArray.slice(1);
    
    if(cmd === `${prefix}hibro`) {
        return message.reply("Hi bro!")
    }
)}
```

Comment: lowercase the input [`cmd.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase), your find replace on that site too

Answer (score 9):

Mostly your solution is to bring to the same format either making lowercase all the letters or capital. It's up to you, but better `lowercase`. Also you can use `trim()` to avoid multiple spaces.

```
const str = 'Whatever Text You    Want';
const res = str.replace(/\s+/g,'').toLowerCase();
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

this shall do the trick.

if you get the message using message.content than replace all of the spaces with dashes using replaceAll and conver it to lower case with .toLowerCase()

```
message.content.replaceAll(' ', '-').toLowerCase()
```

Comment: thanks for your reply..but replaceAll is not working instead of this i used replace(/\s/g)

Comment: Thanks for you contribution. Consider editing to add an explanation to improve the quality of this post, increase long term value for future visitors to learn and apply you insight to their own issues, and increase your odds of getting upvotes

Answer (score 0):

Compare after making string lowercase. Example

```
var str = "Hello World!";
var res = str.toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert all the letters to the small case then Javascript has `toLowerCase()` method available for strings. To replace the whitespace you can use the `replace` method.

So the following code will give the output: `hibro!`

`"Hi bro!".toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g,'')`

`/\s/g` finds all the occurrences of white space in the strings.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try the below,

```
const str1 = 'Whatever Text You    Want';
    var k=[...str1.toLocaleLowerCase()];
    var s='';
    k.forEach(temp=>{
        s+=(temp!=' ')?temp:''
    })
```

a.trim() only removes the trailing spaces at the end and the beginning of the string, it won't capture in between spaces.

May be you can refer about String.prototype.trim() MDN docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim)